# UICollectionViewCell content overlapping other cells

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to display a `UITableView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`, that would be displayed over the other cells.

(The other cells don't have a table view)

Here's what I get so far :

[image]

Result : The `UITableView` is displayed behind the other cells.

I've set `clipToBounds = NO` to the content view of the cell, so that the table view gets displayed outside the cell content.

After looking at the View Hierarchy inspector, it seems that the cell containing the table view is lower than the other cells. I think it should be on the same level ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is working for now :

```
self.layer.zPosition = 1000;
```

(Inside `UICollectionViewCell`)